# How to get images to automatically reload in a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to Vue, I have an app running with a few different pages. One of the pages I'm trying to have is one that displays all images that are found in a directory on my host and to have them auto reload whenever the image changes (a separate app updates these images every 10 seconds). I've been able to display all the images (although only by listing them) and I can't seem to figure out how to get the pictures to auto refresh. Below is the code, any help is much appreciated.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="media-display">
    <figure class="media-post" v-for="(image, index) in images" v-bind:key="image.id" >
      <img :key="index" :src="getImage(index)" v-bind:alt="image" width="580" height="390" v-bind:key="index" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      images: [
        '/charts/chart1.png?rnd='+Math.random(),
        '/charts/chart2.png?rnd='+Math.random(),
        '/charts/chart3.png?rnd='+Math.random(),
      ],
      id : 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImage(index) {
      return this.images[index]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.media-post {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vmin;
  //border-radius: 2vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.media-post img {
  //border-radius: 1vmin;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.media-post figcaption {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Will the images have different source paths after every update?

Comment: I was thinking to keep the source path the same. However if it makes it easier, I can change it for every update too.

Comment: If the source paths are the same, then using `setInterval()` within the `mounted` hook should do the trick. The `data` option is reactive and will cause a component reload on any changes, so you could create a dummy property within `data` and change its value within `setInterval()` every n number of seconds.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how that would look? I tried using setInterval() but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Had to post as an answer because code blocks are not allowed in comments. See below.

Comment: Thank you @zer0kompression, however I tried the code below, and still my images are not refreshing. I don't get errors when I compile and there are no errors on the chrome developer console. Do you know where I can look to see if it is doing something every 10 seconds?

Comment: You can write a `console.log('some text')` within the `setInterval()` block and it should show in the developer console. Also, as a test, try replacing the `mounted` hook with the `created` hook. For all of it, try opening the app in an incognito window in case your browser is caching the images.

Comment: I do see that console.log writes text to the developer console every 10 seconds, so that proves the setInterval works, however the pictures stay the same

Comment: Any reason why you're using `:key` for the `<img>` within the `<figure />` element?

Comment: No, I think at one point I added to try and get it to change it within a setInterval() to see if that would work

Comment: Also, you're not providing the proper value for `:key` on the `<figure />` element. There is no value for `image.id`. In this case, you could use `:key=index`. Using indices as keys are not recommended, but it should help until you get better IDs for the images.

Comment: Now I do see what seems to be some sort of reload in the developer console, I can see the "figure" sections in the elements section flash every 10 seconds. However the images are still the same. I added "?rnd='+Math.random()" to my image names in data to see if their names are getting updated and its just chrome caching the images, but the images names do not change. Do I need to have vue force rerender the data?

Comment: To eliminate caching issues, use a private or inconito window (`Ctrl + Shift + N` for Chrome). Properties in `data` will remain the same by design unless they're changed by a method or assigned new values during the `created` or `mounted` hooks.

Comment: Rewrite the `img` tag within the `figure` element like the following:
`<img v-for="(image, index) in images" :key=index :src="getImage(index)" v-bind:alt="image" width="580" height="390"/>`
Remove all attributes except `class` from the `figure` element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to regenerate the random number suffix periodically. Untested:

```vue
<img
  v-for="url of images"
  :key="url"
  :src="url + '?rnd=' + cacheKey"
/>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    images: [
      '/charts/chart1.png',
      '/charts/chart2.png',
      '/charts/chart3.png',
    ],
    cacheKey: +new Date(),
  };
},

created() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.cacheKey = +new Date();
  }, 60 * 1000);
},

destroyed() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
},
```

If it isn't clear, `+new Date()` returns the number of seconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)).

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly? Would you happen to know how I can have it load all the *png images in that directory without having to manually list them?

Comment: That would require support from your server to provide the list of images. It would be best to ask it in a separate question.